# Iterating JSON received from webservice using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In the simple code snippet below, i am getting a JSON response from a php page and then trying to iterate it and alert out the name field on each JSON objects. But it doesnt alert out anything.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>AJAX DB</title>
</head>

<body>

  Name: <input type="text" id="name">
  <input type="submit" id="name-submit">
  <div id="formatted-data"></div>
  <div id="name-data"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script >

  $('input#name-submit').on('click',function(){
    var name = $('input#name').val();

    if($.trim(name) != ''){
      $.post('appservice.php', {search_key: 'users_search', search_value:  name}, function(data){
        //$('div#name-data').text(search_data);
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
          alert(obj.name);
        });
      });
    }
  });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

sample JSON

```
[
  {
    "id": 18927441,
    "id_str": "18927441",
    "name": "IGN",
    "screen_name": "IGN",
    "location": "San Francisco, CA"
  }
]
```

Comment: If you `console.log(data)`, is it a `string` or an `object`? If it's a string, then you need to use `data = JSON.parse(data);` to convert it from json to object first.

Comment: Thanks a lot! cant believe i was missing such a basic point.

Can you explain why is it like that though? I was just copy pasting the response in an online JSON parser and it detected the echoed  out string as valid JSON. So i thought it was already a JSON object.

Comment: Because you didn't pass `dataType` to [.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), so jquery guess it based on return object, which would based on the return info from your php, and it seems jquery guess it's `text`, so it didn't parse it for you, instead it gives you the raw content. Things would change if you pass `json` as 4th param.

Comment: makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't utilize JSON while it is still in JSON string form. You need to parse it to use it. Try:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```